# large drop down storage using AmplifyJS

Tags: jquery, amplifyjs

I have 3 drop down select box.First drop down box contains 10 data,As of now data is populating from server using php/ajax.

When I request from first drop down,the second and third drop down data updating from server.The second and third drop down contains around 30,000 records.I mean
each second and third drop down box individually contains this much data and it takes 1 minute to load.I am thinking AmplifyJS is the solution to store the data in locally and get it from local storage.My approach is correct ? please help

Answer (score 0):

If you have this much data, you really should use some autocomplete component instead of a dropdown; this is both for your server's sake (less data to transmit) and for your user's sake (less lines to wade through).

Comment: I use chosen dropdown,It has the facility of auto complete once it  is fully loaded to client side.My client doesn't need auto complete,he wants only dropdown

Comment: Okay, but just keep in mind that using an autocomplete option would allow for a more responsive application, since it would only have to download part of the data; that would mean the user would have to wait less time for the combo to load. ;) Maybe you could use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to have a dropdown which autocompletes itself using AJAX requests depending on what the user typed.

Comment: Then again, using AmplifyJS for storing the data clientside may be a good idea as long as the records don't change too often; if the data does change, you may have have to implement an automatic incremental update routine to keep the local storage up-to-date.